# Finding a basis for least squares approximation of fourth degree polynomial in second degree polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got $f(x)=x^4+x^3$, and
I'm trying to find an approximation of f(x) by polynomials in $P_2(\mathbb{R})$. In order to do so, I believe I need an orthonormal basis. I'm comfortable with normalizing bases, but I need to get a basis in the first place.

I understand that I can make $f(x)$ from the basis $\beta = \{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4\}$, but how can I get a basis that's in $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and contains $f(x)$?

Thanks for your time. I'm pretty confused here.

Comment: By least squares, do you mean the sum of squares of the differences at points $x_{1}$. $x_{2}$. $\ldots$, $x_{m}$, or you do you mean the sum of squares of the differences squared over a range of $x$ values, or something else?

Comment: The sum of the squares of the differences. It doesn't have to be the least squares approximation, but that's the method I'm most familiar with. I'm just trying to approximate $f(x)$ with polynomials in $P_\mathbb{R}(2)$.

Comment: Rather than using a finite set of points to measure the difference, you might be better off minimizing $\int_{a}^{b} (f(x)-p(x))^{2} dx$ to minimize the average squared error over the interval $[a,b]$.  It's likely that this was what you were asked to do in an assignment.